# Javascript in master page not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have a javascript function for confirmation :

```
function confirm() {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to log out?")
    if (answer) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and on my link I call this function :

```
<div class="header">
                <a href="" class="logo"></a>
                <div class="topToolbar">
                    <span><a href="/Logout.aspx" onclick="return confirm();">Log Out</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The issue is that it never calls the javascript function, tried to put alerts and didnt get anything.

I even tried to do it with jquery bt still same thing the only difference was that I could get alert on document ready function.

Comment: Although it's answered, note that you were calling it recursively

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should rename your function. `confirm` is reserved for, well, the `confirm` function:

```
function shouldContinue() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to log out?");
}
```

and then:

```
<a href="/Logout.aspx" onclick="return shouldContinue();">Log Out</a>
```

---

Actually to be more precise `confirm` is not a reserved keyword. You could override the `confirm` function. And that's what you did. Except that inside this overridden function you called it once again and thus ending in a recursive endless loop.

Here's an example how you could override it:

```
window.confirm = function(msg) {
    alert('this is the overriden confirm function');
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Not that it's reserved. In fact you can overload it. Tried on firebug ._.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function in the onclick, you need to rename the function so it doesn't clash with confirm.

```
logoutMessage = function() {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to log out?")
    if (answer) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
} ​

<div class="header">
    <a href="" class="logo"></a>
    <div class="topToolbar">
        <span><a href="/Logout.aspx" onclick="return logoutMessage()">Log Out</a></span>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Ideally you wouldn't use the `onclick` attribute in the html.  You can keep it purely in the javascript by using an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), which is clearer and avoids have to pollute the markup.  If you give the logout link an id you can do:

```
document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", logoutConfirm);
```

That will call the function on click.

Comment: How bout just returning `confirm(...)`? :-P